# sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file when running dDango test coverage inside a docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, code-coverage

Hello I have seen many questions with this title but I couldn't fix my issue with any of the answers.

I'm setting up a Django project within a docker container but I also want to run the test coverage inside the docker container because my app is using PostgreSQL database which is also configured in Docker.

Basically when I run the command  ``` docker-compose run web sh -c "coverage run manage.py test && coverage report"` ``locally it works fine but the same command does not work on ```Travis ci```

Here is the error I get when the same command runs on Travis

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/coverage", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 827, in main
    status = CoverageScript().command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 555, in command_line
    return self.do_run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 710, in do_run
    self.coverage.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/control.py", line 649, in save
    data = self.get_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/control.py", line 703, in get_data
    if self._collector and self._collector.flush_data():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/collector.py", line 425, in flush_data
    self.covdata.add_lines(self.mapped_file_dict(self.data))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/sqldata.py", line 437, in add_lines
    self._choose_lines_or_arcs(lines=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/sqldata.py", line 494, in _choose_lines_or_arcs
    with self._connect() as con:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/sqldata.py", line 299, in _connect
    self._create_db()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/sqldata.py", line 248, in _create_db
    with db:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/sqldata.py", line 1026, in __enter__
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/sqldata.py", line 1008, in _connect
    self.con = sqlite3.connect(filename, check_same_thread=False)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
The command "docker-compose run web sh -c "coverage run manage.py test && coverage report"" exited with 1.
```

Please help me if you can.

MY TRAVIS CI

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.8"

services:
  - docker

before_script:
  - pip install docker-compose

script:
  - docker-compose run web sh -c "flake8 && python manage.py migrate"
  - docker-compose run web sh -c "coverage run manage.py test && coverage report"
after_success:
  - docker-compose run web sh -c "coveralls"
```

DOCKER FILE

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
LABEL Mwibutsa Floribert 

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apk update && apk add gcc libc-dev make git libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN \
    apk add --no-cache python3 postgresql-libs && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir && \
    apk --purge del .build-deps



RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN adduser -D mwibutsa
RUN chown mwibutsa -R /app/

USER mwibutsa
```

DATABASE CONFIGURATION

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
    }
}
```

Note: I'm getting those environment variables from docker

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue on `CircleCI`

```    
snowflake_connection = sqlite3.connect("snowflake.db")
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: If I remember it very well, there were some issues that were being caused by the alpine version of the image I was using. The ``` pyhton3.8-alpine``` was not installing git inside the docker image and I had to install it in the image which is being created.

Comment: Hi @Mwibutsa Floribert, I tried adding git to the image (I am using `python:3.8-alpine` too), the test still fail with unable to open database file. I think the error may have to do with relative filepath of the DB.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be caused by your configuration in `settings.py`.

Make sure that you are using an absolute and not a relative path with something like this `~/`. You absolute path should be the full path, e.g.

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
'NAME': '/home/path/to/your/db/data.sqlite3'
```

It couls also be caused by this line `RUN chown mwibutsa -R ~/` from your `DockerFile`. Consider changing this to an absolute path as well.

Comment: I'm actually using PostgreSQL I have no idea to why coverage is using SQLite3

Comment: Since you are running PostgreSQL within your docker contains you wouldn't have to specify that in your services. That's only needed if you are testing an external PostgreSQL db, see [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#postgresql) on that. Try and remove thePostgreSQL from services and see if that has any impact?

Comment: This [guide](https://www.rockyourcode.com/docker-compose-postgres-and-travis-ci/) walks through on a similar build setup. You can try use this and identify your own mistake.

Comment: Not yet, I'm still struggling and looking for a way to do it manually in case it keeps misbehaving

Answer (score 0):

Have the similar issue, but civerage didn't work locally: the issue was resolved by expanding permissions to project folder.